# Proper way to divide into 4 pieces an android layout

Tags: android, listview, layout, row, android-relativelayout

what I want to achieve is, divide the rows layout described in picture below. what should I do  to achieve dividing the row into 3 exactly same size and 1 unknown size? X are same size and i dont know and dont want to specify if its not necessary...

[image]

EDIT: buttons are on the left , center, and right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `LinearLayout` inside a `RelativeLayout`. Put 3 items inside the `LinearLayout` and give them the same `weight`. Put the unknown item to the right of the `LinearLayout` with the help of `RelativeLayout`.

Left elements will align themselves according to the right-one's width.
Here's the code: https://gist.github.com/3772838

And here 2 screenshots with different sized right most elements:

http://goo.gl/Nezmn

http://goo.gl/XbQwL

Kolay gelsin =)

Answer (score 1):

Does your extreme left size has a minimum width ?
If so, you should use a LinearLayout with horizontal orientation.
It could contains 2 LinearLayout, one which contains 3 Views (your Buttons) with 0 width and with 1 weight each and the other LinearLayout has a minimumWidth set.
Instead of the marginRight, you could specify a width for the first layout.

Ted Hopp get it right ;)

Comment: This will not work. The first inner `LinearLayout` will not expand to fill the available space. It is also unnecessary to nest `LinearLayout`s; all four buttons can go in a single `LinearLayout`.

Comment: I put a second LinearLayout because I didn't catch that he wanted to have 4 buttons ;)

Comment: without trying your answer, is ? can be wrap_content?, Actually what i want is ? is wrap content width and the others fill the available space.

Comment: @KaaN - Not really. This approach requires knowing the width of the fourth button because that width is used to set the right margin of the container layout.

Comment: In all case, I don't think you can do want you want without specify at least one width.
(Wrap_content for the last view should make it, if it's a button with some text for example)

Comment: its a button with image^^ how can I do that with this info?

Comment: How yap, so sorry haha, didn't look at it

Answer (score 1):

You can use `android:layout_weight` to distribute extra space proportionally. You want the three left buttons to absorb all the extra width, so the right (fourth) button should have the default weight of 0. Since you also want them to have the same width, the easiest is to assign them a width of 0dp and give them all the same weight:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/rlayoutParent">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rlayoutButtons" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlayoutOther"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rlayoutButtons" android:gravity="right">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

you cab use the layout_weight attribute. give all the x layout the same weight and the question mark a diffrent weight until the screen will devide as u like